# Assigning new strings with conditional match

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have an issue about replacing strings with the new ones conditionally.

I put short version of my real problem so far its working however I need a better solution since there are many rows in the real data.

```
strings <- c("ca_A33","cb_A32","cc_A31","cd_A30")
```

Basicly I want to replace `strings` with `replace_strings`. First item in the `strings` replaced with the first item in the `replace_strings`.

```
replace_strings <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4")
```

So the final string should look like

```
final string <- c("ca_A1","cb_A2","cc_A3","cd_A4")
```

I write some simple function `assign_new`

```
assign_new <- function(x){

  ifelse(grepl("A33",x),gsub("A33","A1",x),
  ifelse(grepl("A32",x),gsub("A32","A2",x),
  ifelse(grepl("A31",x),gsub("A31","A3",x),
  ifelse(grepl("A30",x),gsub("A30","A4",x),x))))

}

assign_new(strings)

[1] "ca_A1" "cb_A2" "cc_A3" "cd_A4"
```

Ok it seems we have solution. But lets say if I have A1000 to A1 and want to replace them from A1 to A1000 I need to do 1000 of rows of `ifelse` statement. How can we tackle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Per @Onyambu's comment, removing `map2_chr` as `paste` is a vectorized function.

```
foo <- function(x, y){
  x <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, "_"), '[', 1))
  paste(x, y, sep = "_"))
}

foo(strings, replace_strings)
```

with x being `strings` and y being `replace_strings`. You first split the `strings` object at the `_` character, and paste with the respective `replace_strings` object.

EDIT:

For objects where there is no positional relationship you could create a reference table (dataframe, list, etc.) and match your values.

```
reference_tbl <- data.frame(strings, replace_strings)

foo <- function(x){
  y <- reference_tbl$replace_strings[match(x, reference_tbl$strings)]
  x <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, "_"), '[', 1))
  paste(x, y, sep = "_")
}

foo(strings)
```

Comment: in the case vectors not ordered how can we do that ? Match A33 to A1 like I did with if else ?

Comment: You could create a reference object outside of the function, and map to that value inside the function.

Comment: This is a much more complete answer than mine. I think this is what you are looking for @Alexander

Comment: Paste is a vectorized function. You do not need the map2_chr..just paste(x,y,sep=“-“)

Answer (score 3):

If your vectors are ordered to be matched, then you can use:

```
> paste0(gsub("(.*_)(.*)","\\1", strings ), replace_strings)
[1] "ca_A1" "cb_A2" "cc_A3" "cd_A4"
```

Comment: All thank you for all your solutions. Hopefully they would useful to other users. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regmatches`.First obtain all the characters that are followed by `_` using `regexpr` then replace as shown below

```
`regmatches<-`(strings,regexpr("(?<=_).*",strings,perl = T),value=replace_strings)
[1] "ca_A1" "cb_A2" "cc_A3" "cd_A4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the fastests but very tractable and easy to maintain:

```
for (i in 1:length(strings)) {
  strings[i] <- gsub("\\d+$", i, strings[i])
}
```

`"\\d+$"` just matches any number at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
strings <- c("ca_A33","cb_A32","cc_A31","cd_A30")
replace_strings <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4")
df <- data.frame(strings, replace_strings)

df <- mutate(rowwise(df),
             strings = gsub("_.*",
                            paste0("_", replace_strings),
                            strings)
             )

df <- select(df, strings)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  strings
  <chr>  
1 ca_A1  
2 cb_A2  
3 cc_A3  
4 cd_A4
```

Answer (score 1):

yet another way:

```
mapply(function(x,y) gsub("(\\w\\w_).*",paste0("\\1",y),x),strings,replace_strings,USE.NAMES=FALSE)
# [1] "ca_A1" "cb_A2" "cc_A3" "cd_A4"
```